# Applying a function for calculating AUC for each subject

Tags: r

I want to calculate the area under the curve(AUC) of concentration-TIME profiles for many subjects (~200 subjects). I am using the package MESS where:

```
AUC = auc(data$TIME,data$CONC, type = "spline")
```

How can I apply it to each unique ID in the data set? and retain the results in R by adding a new "AUC" column in the original data set?

The data has the following columns:

```
ID TIME CONC 
1   0    0
1   2    4
1   3    7
2   0    0
2   1    NA
2   3    5
2   4    10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `summarise()`:

```
library(MESS)
library(dplyr)

foo = read.table(text = "ID TIME CONC 
1   0    0
1   2    4
1   3    7
2   0    0
2   1    NA
2   3    5
2   4    10", header=T)

foo %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(AUC = auc(TIME,CONC, type = "spline"), .groups="keep")

#  ID      AUC
#1  1  9.12500
#2  2 12.08335
```

If you want to keep all your columns from the original dataset, you could use `mutate()`:

```
foo %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(AUC = auc(TIME, CONC, type = "spline"))

#  ID TIME CONC      AUC
#1  1    0    0  9.12500
#2  1    2    4  9.12500
#3  1    3    7  9.12500
#4  2    0    0 12.08335
#5  2    1   NA 12.08335
#6  2    3    5 12.08335
#7  2    4   10 12.08335
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the `dplyr`solution provided by @jazzurro is the way to go, but here's a `base` approach for good measure.

```
d <- read.table(text='ID TIME CONC 
1   0    0
1   2    4
1   3    7
2   0    0
2   1    NA
2   3    5
2   4    10', header=TRUE)


library(MESS)   
auc <- t(sapply(split(d, d$ID), function(x) {
  data.frame(ID=x$ID[1], auc=auc(x$TIME, x$CONC, type='spline'))
}))

merge(d, auc)

#   ID TIME CONC      auc
# 1  1    0    0    9.125
# 2  1    2    4    9.125
# 3  1    3    7    9.125
# 4  2    0    0 12.08335
# 5  2    1   NA 12.08335
# 6  2    3    5 12.08335
# 7  2    4   10 12.08335
```