# Implementation of Cobb-Douglas Utility Function to calculate Receiver Operator Curve & AUC

Tags: r, dataframe, auc

this is not a hard problem from my understanding, however, I have minimal experience with different R functions and problem solving within it. **The text is long to provide a thorough understanding rather than complexity.** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to utilize a Cobb-Douglas Utility Function [[x^a * y^(1 - a)]](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?u(x,y)=X%5E%7Ba%7D*X%5E%7B1-a%7D) to calculate a Receiver Operator Curve for every point of alpha for a final result of an AUC vs. Alpha graph.

If you are unfamiliar with ROC - I'd recommend [GoogleDev](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc)  & [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic).

Here are my two initial tables: df, alpha

```
view(df)
```

| ID | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 |
| B | 2 | 5 |
| C | 3 | 6 |

```
Alpha <- seq(0.1,0.3,by = 0.1))
view(alpha)
```

| row # | Alpha value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0.3 |

***Wanted function #1 here to combine Alpha to XY pairs*** w/

```
view(combined_wanted_result)
```

| ID | X | Y | Alpha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.1 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.2 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.3 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.1 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.2 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.3 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.1 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.2 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.3 |

The combined result is wanted due to the fact that every XY pair (1/4, 2/5, 3/6) is unique&connected and I do not want to mix those vales (bad_ex: 1/5, 3/5, 2/6).

I'm trying to use the Cobb-Douglas Utility Function so that I can make a table for every iteration of alpha. [The documentation in R does not seem to be appropriate for my use](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/Recon/html/cobb_douglas.html).

Z = (x^a * y^(1 - a)
***Wanted cobb_douglas function #2 here***

```
View(cobb_douglas)
```

| ID | X | Y | Alpha | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.1 | 3.482 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.2 | 3.031 |
| A | 1 | 4 | 0.3 | 2.649 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.1 | 4.562 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.2 | 4.163 |
| B | 2 | 5 | 0.3 | 3.798 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.1 | 5.598 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.2 | 5.223 |
| C | 3 | 6 | 0.3 | 4.876 |

This View(cobb_douglas) will then be grouped by alpha and an ROC curve created from those Z value in comparison to a given an absolute identification.

```
view(Abs)
```

| ID | Abs |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 1 |

```
#Grab all Z values of certain alpha, matched by common ID to get absolute
view(0.1_alpha)
view(0.2_alpha)
```

| ID | Alpha | Z | Abs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.1 | 3.482 | 1 |
| B | 0.1 | 4.562 | 0 |
| C | 0.1 | 5.598 | 1 |

| ID | Alpha | Z | Abs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.2 | 3.031 | 1 |
| B | 0.2 | 4.163 | 0 |
| C | 0.2 | 5.223 | 1 |

**Wanted function #3 - creating an ROC table (w/ Z&Abs) of each alpha table to calculate AUC**
*Note, the AUC values are not given here* - This table will be used to plot Alpha vs. AUC.

| Alpha | AUC |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | ? |
| 0.2 | ? |
| 0.3 | ? |

What I've tried prompt:

My initial stick up which I got while trying to solve this problem with 'expand.grid' to plot every alpha to an XY pair. But the X&Y values kept getting mixed with each other leading to unwanted value pairs such as 1/5, 3/5, 2/6.

I have reviewed similar articles in Stackoverflow and some of them solve the further problem of calculating the AUC. However the initial data matching I am still lost on.

Similar issue links:
[MLE for Cobb Douglas function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977794/mle-for-cobb-douglas-function)
[How to calculate a partial area under the curve (AUC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680994/how-to-calculate-a-partial-area-under-the-curve-auc)
[How to calculate area under the curve (AUC) in several data series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499603/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-in-several-data-series)
[How to calculate the AUC from a ROC plot without the underlying data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634388/how-to-calculate-the-auc-from-a-roc-plot-without-the-underlying-data)
[How to calculate the AUC of a graph in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424572/how-to-calculate-the-auc-of-a-graph-in-r)
[Applying a function for calculating AUC for each subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583182/applying-a-function-for-calculating-auc-for-each-subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not entirely clear how all your desired outputs should look, here is a partial solution that addresses some of the things you are trying to achieve. If there are other elements in need of consideration, please comment below and I will update my answer.

At its heart, your question relates to data manipulation and the `dplyr` package is probably the easiest way to achieve your goals. If you haven't already, install `dplyr` and `MESS` (for the second example) prior to running this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MESS)

# Your data as described
df <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
                 X = 1:3,
                 Y = 4:6)

Alpha <- data.frame(row = 1:3,
                    Alpha = seq(0.1,0.3,by = 0.1))

Abs <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:3],
                  Abs = c(1,0,1))

# Create full dataset
result <- df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(Alpha))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(., Alpha, by = "row") %>%
  mutate(Z = (X^Alpha * Y^(1 - Alpha))) %>%
  left_join(., Abs, by = "ID") %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  ungroup()

data.frame(result)

  ID X Y Alpha        Z Abs
1  A 1 4   0.1 3.482202   1
2  A 1 4   0.2 3.031433   1
3  A 1 4   0.3 2.639016   1
4  B 2 5   0.1 4.562218   0
5  B 2 5   0.2 4.162766   0
6  B 2 5   0.3 3.798289   0
7  C 3 6   0.1 5.598198   1
8  C 3 6   0.2 5.223303   1
9  C 3 6   0.3 4.873514   1

# Create table with AUC for each Alpha (NOTE: edit columns in auc() if incorrect)
result1 <- df %>% 
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(Alpha))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(., Alpha, by = "row") %>%
  mutate(Z = (X^Alpha * Y^(1 - Alpha))) %>%
  left_join(., Abs, by = "ID") %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  group_by(Alpha) %>%
  summarize(AUC = auc(Z, Abs, type = "spline"), .groups="keep")

data.frame(result1)

  Alpha       AUC
1   0.1 0.7930400
2   0.2 0.8208068
3   0.3 0.8363540
```

***Update based on OP's comments***

To use multiple sequences of alpha values dynamically in a loop, the following method works. NOTE: I have kept your column names consistent with your original question (rather than the ones stated in your comments) to avoid confusing others who may happen across this answer:

```
# Create list of alpha sequences to iterate over
alphaseq <- list(seq(0.1, 0.3, by = 0.1),
                 seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1),
                 seq(0.01, 0.1, by = 0.01))

# Create empty df to hold the results
auc_results <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 0, ncol = 3))
# iteration column added to identify which seq() was used
colnames(auc_results) <- c("iteration",
                           "Alpha",
                           "AUC")

# Iterate over alphaseq and save results to auc_results
for(i in seq(alphaseq)) {
  
  # Create Alpha dynamically
  Alpha <- data.frame(Alpha = alphaseq[[i]],
                      row = 1:length(alphaseq[[i]]))
  
  tmp <- df %>% 
    slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(Alpha))) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
    left_join(., Alpha, by = "row") %>%
    mutate(Z = (X^Alpha * Y^(1 - Alpha))) %>%
    left_join(., Abs, by = "ID") %>%
    select(-row) %>%
    group_by(Alpha) %>%
    summarize(AUC = auc(Z, Abs, type = "spline"), .groups="keep") %>%
    mutate(iteration = i) %>%
    relocate(iteration)
  
  auc_results <- rbind(auc_results, tmp)
  rm(tmp)
  
}

# Result
data.frame(auc_results)

   iteration Alpha       AUC
1          1  0.10 0.7930400
2          1  0.20 0.8208068
3          1  0.30 0.8363540
4          2  0.10 0.7930400
5          2  0.20 0.8208068
6          2  0.30 0.8363540
7          2  0.40 0.8419765
8          2  0.50 0.8394922
9          2  0.60 0.8303900
10         2  0.70 0.8159135
11         2  0.80 0.7971144
12         2  0.90 0.7748883
13         2  1.00 0.7500000
14         3  0.01 0.7551021
15         3  0.02 0.7600145
16         3  0.03 0.7647423
17         3  0.04 0.7692901
18         3  0.05 0.7736625
19         3  0.06 0.7778638
20         3  0.07 0.7818983
21         3  0.08 0.7857700
22         3  0.09 0.7894826
23         3  0.10 0.7930400
```

Comment: @quartztester - for future reference, all this should be asked as a new question but I know what it's like when you're just starting out so have happily updated my answer. And pro tip: to help get a handle on piping, highlight the code up to each %>% in turn and run e.g. `df %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(Alpha)))` and run, then `df %>% slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(Alpha))) %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(row = 1:n())` and so on.

Comment: Will do on the new questions and thank you. I deleted my previous scratch work and will re-add the comment you were replying to - dynamically adjusting the alpha intervals.

I'm currently in the process of implementing this solution and scaling backup into my actual dataset. I simplified my question the best I could so that a solution would be relatively easy to post for users.  I'll mark this as complete as soon as I verify if those domains are the same or different. 

I extraordinarily appreciate the help you have offered.

Comment: I can't upvote because of my low reputation from a new account :(. Accepting I can do soon!

Comment: I'm currently extending features on this dataset to use 3 alphas. Will add here - for the summarize AUC line 'linear' seems to be more appropriate for the data. 'spline' seems to pop out errors and no dataset.